# Using a CollectionView to add a tile effect when the user types

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a test application I have made for a part of my workflow. What I am trying to achieve is a fancy way of showing the user what they are typing for a Word styled game.

At the moment this is the approach but there could be an easier/better route. I have a `UITextField` which is not shown to the user and the keyboard is shown on `viewDidLoad`. What I am trying to have happen is each time a letter is pressed on the keyboard a new Tile showing the letter capitalised is added to the screen area above i.e. 'W', then another letter would mean another tile added i.e. 'I' next to the previous...

I have setup a `UICollectionView` and custom cell with a label in, that is all. The VC is the dataSource of the `UICollectionView`. The `UITextField` also has its `delegate` set to the `self` (the VC).

I cannot work out how to have the tiles (cells) created each letter.

```
#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark - Key board delegate methods
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
NSString *lastLetterTyped = [textField.text substringFromIndex:[textField.text length] - 1];

[self.wordArray addObject:lastLetterTyped];
[self.tileCollectionView reloadData];

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark - Collection View Data Source Methods
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // we're going to use a custom UICollectionViewCell, which will hold an image and its label
    //
    WordCVCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // make the cell's title the actual NSIndexPath value
    NSString *lastLetter = [self.typedWord substringFromIndex:[self.typedWord length] - 1];
    cell.label.text = lastLetter;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}
```

Should read as

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    [self.wordArray count];
}
```

This will trigger the following the same number of times as there are objects in your array.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // we're going to use a custom UICollectionViewCell, which will hold an image and its label
    //
    WordCVCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // make the cell's title the actual NSIndexPath value
    NSString *lastLetter = [self.wordArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.label.text = lastLetter;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that. Do you know how to change the width of the boxes(cells) that are created? I need these to work with Auto Layout I believe so that they get smaller as more are created and fit on screen

Comment: You can implement methods from UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout for the method collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a NSMutableArray that you will add to each time the user types a character. For that you need to hook up your controller to UITextfieldDelegate. After that each time you add to this array you need to call [collectionView reloadData] and your number of items will be [myMutableCharacterArray count];

So basically each time a user types a letter, add it to a mutable array and call [collectionView reload data] to refresh the collectionview.

Comment: I have added an EDIt to the above code. I now use an array and add an object of the last letter typed into the text field. Then reload the data. How do I setup the cell so that each cells label is the text from the arrays object? Also how do I know these will be ordered in the correct way?